# It is hard to distinguish between preposition and adverb in this sentence

Tags: grammar

There is a simple sentence below.

> We prepared a picnic lunch and drove down by the river.

Is "down" a preposition or adverb in this sentence?

Plesase, let me know.

Comment: Are you asking whether the quote should be parsed with “drove down” or “down by the river”?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to parse ***down by** the river* is to think of *down by* as a [double preposition](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/preposition-examples.html):

> I can’t get *out of* going to the meeting.
>   They made a wall *out of* old tires.
>   She sat *across from* her father-in-law.
>   There’s a cabin *up on* the ridge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!. but I think that down might be adverb.

Comment: I don't think it's that simple. 'There’s a cabin upon the ridge' / 'There’s a cabin on top of the ridge' show compound prepositions. 'There’s a cabin up on the ridge' / 'There’s a cabin down on the ridge below us' seem to show what I'd call double preposition structures, perhaps deleted from 'There’s a cabin up there on the ridge'.

Answer (score 0):

In [English Grammar: A University Course by Angela Downing & ‎Philip Locke](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=isbn:0415287871) is found this syntactic analysis on how prepositional phrases may be realised:

> **Realisations of the complement element of a prepositional phrase**
>
> The complement element of a PP is most typically realised by a nominal
> group, but it may also be realised by the classes of groups and
> clauses shown below. Simple nouns and pronouns, adjectives and adverbs
> are treated as 'groups' represented by the head:
>
> - *noun groups*:
>
> at home / after which / on account of his age
>
> - *adjectival groups*:
>
> in private / at last / for good
>
> - *adverbial groups*:
>
> for ever / since when / until quite recently
>
> - *prepositional phrases*:
>
> from out of the forest / except in here
>
> - (*+ finite wh-clauses; wh- + to-infinitive clauses and -ing clauses*)

[re-formatted]

So this would license at least the structure of [{down} by the river] as a prepositional phrase containing a prepositional phrase. This is really a device for adding two adverbial qualifiers in a condensed form: 'We drove alongside the river, which is down in the valley'.

'The mouse ran from under the sofa' and

'There is a cobweb up under the shelf'

use the same device for the same reason.

Note that 'He came down on Tuesday' must be analysed very differently; 'On Tuesday, he came down' shows that the temporal PP is quite distinct, quite separate from the preceding word 'down' in this case. You can't re-order the true 'double preposition' construction to say 'Under the shelf, there is a cobweb up.'

Here, 'down' would traditionally be classed as an adverb, but by many as an intransitive preposition (no matter which order the sentence was written in).

Comment: thanks for your answer..!!

Answer (score -1):

> **We  prepared  a  picnic  lunch  and  drove  down  the  road  by  the  river.**

.  I  think  **down**    is  a  preposlition  because  if  we  remove  it   , it  becomes  we  drove the  road which  is  meaningless.Besides, down is  followed by  a  noun so  it  is  preposition..**By** is  clearly  a preposition  meaning  **by  the  side  of** .

He  came in  ( in  adverb)

He  came  in/ into the  room( preposition)

Here  is  a  link which  shows  **down**  as  a  preposition.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/down_1

Comment: I think that your answer is wrong. I clicked on your hyperlink. so I found that the meaning is different with up sentence.

Comment: It is not a phrasal verb.

Comment: thanks for your answer. by the way, is it the same meaning between phrasal verb and idiom?

Answer (score -1):

A preposition usually has an object, whereas an adverb doesn't.

Comment: thanks for your answer.!!

Comment: Read the edited one. Here, 'down' is an adverb.